# Security measures to be taken while building photo sharing website

Tags: php, security, photo-gallery

I am building a photo sharing website in php. I have almost completed it. I want to know what are the security measures we should take in storing images. I am using file system to store the images. How can I make it secure? Is there anything I can use to password protect the directories in which the images are stored?

Comment: Why do you treat your current implementation as insecure?

Comment: @zerkms: It should be secure in the sense that you cannot have access to directories directly. Like thru address bar

Answer (score 1):

The biggest thing is to make sure it cannot be accessed directly. The files should be stored outside of the web root and a script should be used to send the image.

This adds overhead but it will make it secure. It will also be somewhat harder to take advantage of CDNs.

Comment: Are you trying to say I have to deny access to the files like using .htaccess displaying 404 error?

Comment: It ultimately depends what you want to do. If you want to control access to the image files. Then you cannot make them accessible directly. You would store them on the file system outside of the public web root. Then use a PHP script that would authenticate access and load the image file.

Comment: I didn't get it. Like if images is my directory then I should place it outside the root folder?

Comment: A web application generally has a public entry point to the application. Its the same directory you set as the document root with the web server configuration. Any files stored in this area should be considered public. PHP can access files outside of that directory. If you want to keep files secure, thats where they should be stored.

Comment: Notably, you can use Apache's mod_xsendfile to allow PHP to check if a user has privileges to view an image, then send it with the 'X-Sendfile' header. https://tn123.org/mod_xsendfile/

Answer (score 0):

Another possible solution - without overhead - consists in restricting the access to your image folder using HTTP basic access authentication. You can maintain the .htaccess and the password file with PHP accordingly with your user's credentials.

If you don't want the browser to popup for the user and password you can provide them using JavaScript.